# Unable to Associate app with the store?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

i have developed a windows universal app and i tried to associate the app with store,

when the association wizard open after the sign in the below error occurs every time.

is this because of my windows store account migrated to new dashboard or any other issue?

i tried after sometime and hit refresh still same issue. How to fix this?

Anybody please help me out.

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: try installing visual studio 2013 update 5

Comment: its working fine now and the issue was from their end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unexpected network error has occurred. The app list cannot be refreshed. Please retry by pressing the Refresh button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821072/an-unexpected-network-error-has-occurred-the-app-list-cannot-be-refreshed-plea)

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing for Windows 10? The Windows Store was closed for Windows 10 applications until last week. So give it another try, it should work now.

http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/30/dev-center-open-for-windows-10-app-submissions-adds-new-features/

Comment: its working fine now and the issue was from their end

Answer (score 0):

Using a VPN to the US made the application list appear.