# An unexpected network error has occurred. The app list cannot be refreshed. Please retry by pressing the Refresh button

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

We have developed a Windows Phone 8.1 app. We are not able to create an app package to upload in the app store. While trying to create the app package for app store we are getting this error:

> "An unexpected network error has occurred. The app list cannot be
>   refreshed. Please retry by pressing the Refresh button"

We are using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition & Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 on Windows 8.1 Enterprise OS. We have been facing this issue since we created and paid our Microsoft dev account and could not even publish our first app. Already tried the workarounds mentioned in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/cf578dab-79f2-46ab-a2aa-50a46041ea20/error-an-unexpected-network-error-has-occured-the-app-list-cannot-be-refreshed-please-retry-by?forum=windowsstore. It did not fix the issue. Please help to resolve this. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by not creating the app package from the project menu, i.e. Project-->Store-->Create App Packages.

Instead, I have created the package by using the Visual Studio command utility:

> msbuild WindowsPhoneProjectName.csproj /p:Platform=ARM;Configuration=Release

Uploaded the generated appx package to store and it is working perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was I was logged into an account that didn't have permissions. I forgot we had a special account used for app deployment as we hadn't submitted to the store in awhile. So make sure you have permissions and are logged into the correct account.

I also updated to the latest version of Visual Studio as other forums said some bugs were fixed in this area so that may have contributed to it working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same problem, and I tried Mriganka Deka's answer. Still was unable to fix the issue as the msbuild command also gave me errors.
After trying a lot of things, I found the solution to my problem.

> Just go to **Project --> Store --> Create App Packages** and when the wizard
>   window appears, **select *'No'* instead of *Yes* option**. That way Visual
>   Studio generates your package file on the local machine and you can
>   upload it to Microsoft Store.

I am posting this answer as I could not find this solution anywhere. Hope it helps anyone else facing this problem.

Comment: but the whole point is to upload it to the app store and how is this possible when we select `No` on that screen?