# An unexpected network error occured.The app list cannot be refreshed. when selecting windows phone(universal) as solution platform

Tags: windows, store, visual-studio-cordova

I created a Cordova (Cordova version 6.0.0) project in visual studio 2015 update 1.
I could build the project without errors by selecting *Windows Phone (universal)* as solution platform.
But when I try to associate to windows app store it gives an error

> An unexpected network error has occurred. The applist cannot be
>   refreshed. Please retry by pressing  Refresh button" in 'select an app
>   name' wizard.

When I googled, several people said that it was a bug of visual studio 2015 update 1 and suggested a workaround.
The workaround is to use *create app packages* option  instead of *Associate App with store*
But in my case both options gave me the same error mentioned above.

Same time I could associate the same project to store by selecting the solution platform as *Windows-ARM*

Is there anything else which could have been gone wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try my approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821072

Answer (score 1):

This unhelpful error message also happens if you don't have a developer account yet, which you have to do separately on the Microsoft site.  Once I registered for that, Visual Studio connected just fine.

Register here.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/store/register

Comment: This also happens to me, even as authorised developer. So just register is not an option. It already explains in the dialog, that you need a developer account.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you found is for a different problem (that will be resolved in Update2)

Can you try the same operation with a Windows Store JS project? Which OS are you using?

If it really is a Network error, I will suggest to try again.

rido

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here. Hope it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36128899/3436376

Wanted to add the above link to my answer in comments, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do so.

> Just go to **Project --> Store --> Create App Packages** and when the wizard
>   window appears, **select *'No'* instead of *Yes* option**. That way Visual
>   Studio generates your package file on the local machine and you can
>   upload it to Microsoft Store.

Comment: The thing is, that the worklow behind the "Yes" option adjusts some parameters as the package id automaticcaly. I would need this, but it does not work.

Comment: the whole point is to upload it to the app store and how is this possible when we select `No` on that screen?