# An unexpected network error has occurred. The app list cannot be refreshed

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, unity-game-engine

We have developed a Windows Phone 8.1 app using UNITY 5. We are not able to create an app package to upload in the app store. While trying to create the app package for app store we are getting this error:

> An unexpected network error has occurred. The app list cannot be refreshed. Please retry by pressing the Refresh button"

We are using `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition` & `Visual Studio Community Edition 2015` on Windows 8.1 Enterprise OS. We have been facing this issue since we created and paid our Microsoft dev account and could not even publish our first app. Already tried the workarounds mentioned in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/cf578dab-79f2-46ab-a2aa-50a46041ea20/error-an-unexpected-network-error-has-occured-the-app-list-cannot-be-refreshed-please-retry-by?forum=windowsstore). It did not fix the issue.

We also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821072/an-unexpected-network-error-has-occurred-the-app-list-cannot-be-refreshed-plea). Doesn't work or us.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here. Hope it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36128899/3436376

Adding the answer below if in future it gets changed.

> Just go to **Project --> Store --> Create App Packages** and when the wizard
>   window appears, **select *'No'* instead of *Yes* option**. That way Visual
>   Studio generates your package file on the local machine and you can
>   upload it to Microsoft Store.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but after two weeks the issue fixed all by itself. So i cant test your answer. Thanks again.

Mods can close this thread.